# What does PHP Composer provide that Git Submodules does not?

Tags: php, git, composer-php, git-submodules

I am working on a project that uses Composer (https://getcomposer.org/) to reference various PHP libraries.

I am also using git submodules (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) to reference various JavaScript libraries (where the libraries point at particular release tags, e.g., "v1.2.34").

In order to simplify the project, I am considering ditching Composer in favour of only using submodules unless Composer provides features that Git Submodules does not. So, **what does PHP Composer provide that Git Submodules does not**?

Comment: They both do versioning, but composer also handles version dependencies (iirc) automatically.

Comment: Git submodules are a horrifying pain in the ass, for starters.

Comment: I don't think this question is primarily opinion-based. The word "advantages" is a bit loaded, but there are objective differences between Composer and Git submodules, and the OP wants to know what they are.

Answer (score 3):

One reason for sticking with Composer is that it [handles autoloading for you](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading):

> For libraries that specify autoload information, Composer generates a `vendor/autoload.php` file. You can simply include this file and you will get autoloading for free.
>
> ```
> require 'vendor/autoload.php';
> ```
>
> This makes it really easy to use third party code. For example: If your project depends on monolog, you can just start using classes from it, and they will be autoloaded.
>
> ```
> $log = new Monolog\Logger('name');
> $log->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(
>     'app.log',
>     Monolog\Logger::WARNING
> ));
>
> $log->addWarning('Foo');
> ```
>
> You can even add your own code to the autoloader by adding an `autoload` field to `composer.json`.
>
> ```
> {
>     "autoload": {
>         "psr-4": {"Acme\\": "src/"}
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Composer will register a PSR-4 autoloader for the `Acme` namespace.

As [Jack points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293916/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-php-composer-over-git-submodules/30294287#comment48685091_30293916), Composer also handles dependencies. That is, if you want to use library `X`, and it depends on libraries `Y` and `Z`, Composer will install all three.

Composer also [supports more flexible versioning](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#next-significant-release-tilde-and-caret-operators-), e.g. "use the most recent 1.2.x version", and it's a *de facto* standard tool when working with modern PHP.